# Intel XDK Geocoding

Tags: intel, intel-xdk

I have created an application using intel XDK that determines the current location on a map. However I can not find any documentation or tutorials on how to convert the latitude and longitude to an address. Does anyone have any useful links or guidancce?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel XDK does not have APIs for converting lat/lng to address, there are other reverse geocoding services, you can use google maps reverse geocoding to convert latitude/longitude to address, more information [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse), example below:

include google maps api script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

here is reverse geocoding method:

```
function reverseGeocode(lat, lng){
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        alert(results[1].formatted_address);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

you can get address by running: `reverseGeocode(45, -122)`

Comment: Do you know if intel xdk makes it possible tutilize the device’s sensor functionality and obtain their current address simply by shaking the device? I cannot find anything on this online

Comment: Thankyou... do you know how I can make this show the street name also?

Comment: Here is more details on geocoder, instead of `formatted_address` you can get other properties https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/